# How to use square bracket after calling function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, brackets

I want to use square bracket after calling a function. It's something like this

function()['Name']

I want the output to be 'Andy'.
How the def function syntax should be? I always get error that says it is not subscriptable. This is my current code

```py
def function1():
    A={'Name':'Andy'}
    return 

function1()['Name']
```

Comment: The function must return something subscriptable like e. g. a dict.

Comment: Your usecase is not clear. What are you trying to achieve with it? Perhaps mention with an example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont realy understand your question. But if you want to use square brackets, and find your value by string, you should use dictionaries.
So the function and printing should look like this
``

```
def function():
    return {'Name':'andy'}
print(function()['Name'])
```

`EDIT: You can do something like this, and that will print the answer, but i dont think its really practicall, because, yo are not storing the name anywhere`

```
def function():
    return {'Name':print('Andy')}

function()['Name']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but can we called Andy without the `print`?

Answer (score 1):

For that to work `function` would have to return a `dict`

```
def function():
    return {'Name': 'Andy', 'Age': 20}

>>> function()['Name']
'Andy'
```

In your example, you would modify your function to the following

```
def function1():
    A = {'Name': 'Andy'}
    return A
```

Comment: To make the output says 'Andy', it need to be 
```
print(function()['Name'])
```
Can we calls 'Andy; without `print`?

Comment: @pangu70 you just need to be running python interactively. -- Then if you just specify a variable, it will be automatically printed.